# 'team' or 'teams' when refering to a specific team?

Tags: word-usage

I found a listening material online. Below is part of the script the website presents:

> On February 3rd, 2008, the New England Patriots were entering the game undefeated, the first time a team has done so since the Miami Dolphins did it back in 1972. That Dolphins **teams** when on to beat the Washington Redskins to complete a perfect undefeated season.

I really think 'team' should be singular here. But even the audio says 'teams'. Is it supposed to be singular or plural? If plural, then what's the grammar behind it? Thanks.

Comment: Was it https://www.elllo.org/english/Step/T001Superbowl.htm ?  **teams** is wrong here, and **when** is also wrong (it should be "went").  I notice that the page also says "**Learan** how there were many surprises at this Super Bowl in 2008."  I would not trust this site for very much.

Comment: It's a typo and should be team, singular. And apparently, there are others, too.

Answer (score 1):

The commentator [says](https://www.elllo.org/english/Step/T001Superbowl.htm)

> That Dolphins **team**<strike>s</strike> <strike>when</strike> **went** on to beat the Washington Redskins